# Run javascript function after another is successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I call a validate form function in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#MainContent_btnRegisterClient').click(function (e) {
        return validateForm('.registerClient', '#MainContent_lblRegStatus', '#MainContent_txtClientEmail', e); 
   });
});
```

Which calls my validateForm and then validateEmail:

```
//globals
var errAllfields = "Please complete all highlighted fields";
var errEmail = "Please enter a valid email address";

//email validator
function validateEmail(sEmail, message) {
var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
if (filter.test($(sEmail).val())) {
    return true;
}
else {
    $(message).text(errEmail);
    $(message).fadeIn();
    $(sEmail).css({
        "border": "1px solid #036447",
        "background": "#B5E0D2"
    });
    return false;
}
}
//textbox validation
function validateForm(className, message, email, e) {
var isValid = true;
//empty validation
$(className).each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
        isValid = false;
        $(message).text(errAllfields);
        $(message).fadeIn();
        $(this).css({
            "border": "1px solid #036447",
            "background": "#B5E0D2"
        });
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({
            "border": "",
            "background": ""
        });
    }
    //prevent form submission
    if (isValid == false)
        e.preventDefault();
});
//if all fields complete
if (isValid == true) {
    //if email field entered then validate
    if (email != null) {
        if (!validateEmail(email, message)) {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
}
```

However I then want to add another function (password and password confirm compare function) to be run after these ones are successful.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  Can I call it straight from my aspx page?

Thanks

Comment: is it a separate function?

Comment: Run it as `callback function`

Comment: Try `return validateForm('.registerClient', '#MainContent_lblRegStatus', '#MainContent_txtClientEmail', e) && validatePassword(.....); `

Comment: Why you don't create a common fucntion to validate all the things, if every thing is fine then its ok otherwise show error message.

Comment: For now the function would be:
`//compare
function compare(field1, field2) {
    if ($(field1).val() != $(field2).val()) {
        alert("no match");
        return false;
    }
}`